# All my scraped text ends up in one big object instead of separate objects with Cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm following a web scraping course that uses Cheerio. I practice on a different website then they use in the course and now I run into the problem that all my scraped text end up in one big object. But every title should end up in it's own object. Can someone see what I did wrong? I already bumbed my head 2 hours on this problem.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = "https://huurgoed.nl/gehele-aanbod";

const scrapeResults = [];

async function scrapeHuurgoed() {
    try {
        const htmlResult = await request.get(url);
        const $ = await cheerio.load(htmlResult);

        $("div.aanbod").each((index, element) => {
            const result = $(element).children(".item");
            const title = result.find("h2").text().trim();
            const characteristics = result.find("h4").text();
            const scrapeResult =  {title, characteristics};
            scrapeResults.push(scrapeResult);
        });

        console.log(scrapeResults);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

scrapeHuurgoed();
```

This is the link to the repo: https://github.com/danielkroon/huurgoed-scraper/blob/master/index.js
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of the way you used selectors. I've modified your script to fetch the content as you expected. Currently the script is collecting `titles` and `characteristics`. Feel free to add the rest within your script.

This is how you can get the required output:

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = "https://huurgoed.nl/gehele-aanbod";

const scrapeResults = [];

async function scrapeHuurgoed() {
    try {
        const htmlResult = await request.get(url);
        const $ = await cheerio.load(htmlResult);

        $("div.item").each((index, element) => {
            const title = $(element).find(".kenmerken > h2").text().trim();
            const characteristics = $(element).find("h4").text().trim();
            scrapeResults.push({title,characteristics});
        });
        console.log(scrapeResults);
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

scrapeHuurgoed();
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was something wrong with my selectors. I had no idea I could directly select the .item instead of the .aanbod. Thank you for your help :)